# jQuery change text box value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to display total price in `sum` label by multiplying `qtyTxt` value (user entered) with `price`. But it doesn't work, the `if` statement is never reached.

```
<input type="text" name="qtyTxt" value="1" size="2" style="width: 25px"/>
<label id="price">${adClicked.price}</label>
<label id="sum">${adClicked.price}</label>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${adClicked.id}"/>

<script>
$(".qtyTxt").bind('change', function () {
    var sum=$(("#price").val())* ($(this).val());
    $("#sum").val('Rs.'+sum);
});
</script>
```

There are no errors in the console and `$("#sum").val('Rs.'+sum);` works fine.

Comment: What is the sympton of 'does not work'? No output? Wrong output?

Comment: `val` is used for getting value of form controls not a `label` element. Use the `.text()` method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`  The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.

2) Another mistake Don't use `val()` for label instead of use `text()` for label

```
var sum= parseInt($("#price").text() , 10) * parseInt($(this).val() ,10);
```

code be

```
$(".qtyTxt").bind('change', function () {
  var sum= parseInt($("#price").text() , 10) * parseInt($(this).val() ,10);
   $("#sum").text('Rs.'+sum);
});
```

Comment: Also, Kings of jQuery do not use the `text` method for getting value of an input, right?

Comment: @Vohuman - I liked you named Kings of Jquery . I changes in my profile as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Two issue:

1) You have error in your code, `$(("#price").val())` should be `$("#price").text()` or `$("#price").html()`

2) You need to parse the values before doing mathematical calculation:

```
var sum=parseInt($("#price").text(),10)*parseInt($(this).val(),10) ;
```